# Inheritance + Class members

Tags: python, oop, inheritance

I'm starting with Python and encountered this weird behaviour (atleast for me):

```
class Parent:
    myStr = ""
    myInt = 0
    myDict = {}
    ....

class ChildA:
    ...
    def ...():
        self.myDict.<something>(...)
        print self.myStr
    ...

class ChildB:
    ...
    def ...():
        self.myDict.<something>(...)
        print self.myStr
    ...
```

Based on my understanding, instances of both ChildA and ChildB should have their own dictionaries. But it turns out that they "share" the dictionary. To fix it, I need to set self.myDict={} in the parent's constructor. On the other hand, myStr and myInt appear to have their intended values. Why does this happen?

Comment: You can't append to a dict :P

Comment: :D But you do understand what I'm trying to say :P

Comment: @Utkarsh Sinha: "But you do understand what I'm trying to say"?  No.  You can't append to a dict.  What you're saying makes no sense.  Fix it, please so that it makes sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`myDict` is class-level, so when Python looks at the instance and doesn't find it, it searches up the inheritence tree until it does.  If you re-bind the name `myDict` anywhere in the instance, then the instance will have its own version.

This behavior is easy to see when using mutable objects such as `dict`, `list`, etc, but more difficult to observe with immutable objects such as `str`, `int`, `tuple`, etc, because in order to 'change' the value of an immutable you have to rebind the name -- something like this:

```
class Foo(object):
    collection = list()
    number = 9
    def change_collection(self, new_member):
        self.collection.append(new_member)
    def change_number(self, new_number):
        self.number = new_number

a = Foo()
b = Foo()
a.change_collection('howdy!')
b.change_number(11)
print a.collection, b.collection     # ['howdy!]  ['howdy!']
print a.number, b.number             # 9  11
print a.collection is b.collection   # True
print a.number is b.number           # False
```

Answer (score 3):

This happens because names bound at the class level belong to the class, not any instance. Therefore, all `myDict` are the same dict. Since dict instances are mutable, changes you make via one class/instance reference show up in all. Strings and numbers are immutable, so they are rebound instead when assigned via a subclass or instance.

Answer (score 2):

This happens because setting `myDict` at the *class* level binds it to the class and *not* instances of the class (that is, all instances will share the same `myDict`).

Comment: I have a few other variables defined like that as well (they're strings and integers). It seems to work with those. I'll add that to the question.

Comment: +1: The better thing to do would be to initialize `myDict` in the parent's `__init__()` method. Then it becomes a distinct instance variable that all children receive.

Comment: It works with those because dicts and strings are immutable, and when you update a property though `self.foo = 42`, it sets or updates the *instance* property (not the class property).

Comment: @Utkarsh: That's because strings and integers are immutable and cannot persist so a more local copy gets created on the instance. Dictionaries (and lists) are mutable and therefore are preserved.

Comment: Ah - got it now! I was thinking like C/C++ I guess.

Comment: You can see this because `ChildA().myDict is ChildB().myDict` will return `True`, as they are the same dictionary (and this will hold for anything defined at the class level which hasn't been overwritten).

Answer (score 0):

The key to the issue is as Ignacio pointed out, mutable vs. immutable.  Here's a link to a lengthy explanation complete with ASCII diagrams:

http://mail.python.org/pipermail/tutor/2001-February/003787.html